# Hdmi Problem with lenovo ideapad s540 on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, lenovo, intel-graphics, hdmi

Recently i bought ideapad s540 and everything is fine with ubuntu 18.04 except hdmi output,when using intel vga it doesnot recognize second display at all and with nvidia 1650 sometimes after reboot it works and sometimes not,randomly !
I tested latest property and opensource drivers, kernel from 4.14 to 5.4.2 , lightdm but didnot work , here is my syslog and kernel log grep with hdmi, i hope anyone can help me with this:

kernel.log

```
grep -i hdmi /var/log/kern.log
Dec 11 07:46:29 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.126481] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 11 07:46:29 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.511235] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
Dec 11 07:46:29 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.511282] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 11 07:46:29 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.511334] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
Dec 11 07:46:29 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.511384] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
Dec 11 07:46:29 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.511439] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input24
Dec 11 07:46:29 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.942339] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input25
Dec 12 02:38:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.124563] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 12 02:38:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.485623] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
Dec 12 02:38:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.485673] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 12 02:38:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.485715] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
Dec 12 02:38:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.485763] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
Dec 12 02:38:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.485809] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input24
Dec 12 02:38:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.956212] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input25
Dec 11 20:05:26 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.125759] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 11 20:05:26 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.605585] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
Dec 11 20:05:26 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.605640] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
Dec 11 20:05:26 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.605688] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
Dec 11 20:05:26 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.605750] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
Dec 11 20:05:26 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.605802] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 11 20:05:26 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.969278] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input25
Dec 11 20:34:05 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.128101] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 11 20:34:05 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.529761] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
Dec 11 20:34:05 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.529799] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
Dec 11 20:34:05 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.529839] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
Dec 11 20:34:05 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.529878] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
Dec 11 20:34:05 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.529919] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 11 20:34:05 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.983667] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input25
Dec 11 20:35:53 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.130001] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 11 20:35:53 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.677649] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
Dec 11 20:35:53 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.677700] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
Dec 11 20:35:53 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.677754] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
Dec 11 20:35:53 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.677811] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
Dec 11 20:35:53 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.677864] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 11 20:35:53 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.978349] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input25
Dec 11 20:42:42 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.130282] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 11 20:42:42 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.729631] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
Dec 11 20:42:42 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.729665] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
Dec 11 20:42:42 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.729709] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
Dec 11 20:42:42 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.729742] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
Dec 11 20:42:42 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.729776] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 11 20:42:42 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.062498] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input25
Dec 11 20:52:25 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.124221] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 11 20:52:25 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.159630] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
Dec 11 20:52:25 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.159684] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
Dec 11 20:52:25 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.159715] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
Dec 11 20:52:25 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.159779] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
Dec 11 20:52:25 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.235871] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
Dec 11 20:52:25 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.588107] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input22
Dec 11 20:57:55 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.128958] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 11 20:57:55 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.868582] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
Dec 11 20:57:55 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.868640] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
Dec 11 20:57:55 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.868689] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
Dec 11 20:57:55 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.868727] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
Dec 11 20:57:55 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.868763] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
Dec 11 20:57:55 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.332542] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input21
Dec 11 22:07:57 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.130008] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 11 22:07:57 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.904517] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
Dec 11 22:07:57 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.904557] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
Dec 11 22:07:57 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.904599] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
Dec 11 22:07:57 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.904645] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
Dec 11 22:07:57 jividijuvent kernel: [    2.904690] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
Dec 11 22:07:57 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.421749] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input21
Dec 11 22:21:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.129920] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 11 22:21:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.094198] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input18
Dec 11 22:21:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.862541] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 11 22:21:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.862567] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
Dec 11 22:21:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.862592] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
Dec 11 22:21:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.862618] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input24
Dec 11 22:21:15 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.862650] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input25
Dec 12 16:11:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.130181] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 12 16:11:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.894773] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
Dec 12 16:11:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.894822] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
Dec 12 16:11:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.894869] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
Dec 12 16:11:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.894927] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
Dec 12 16:11:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.894976] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
Dec 12 16:11:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.285604] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input22
Dec 12 14:14:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.125908] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 12 14:14:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.429179] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
Dec 12 14:14:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.429212] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
Dec 12 14:14:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.429239] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
Dec 12 14:14:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.429266] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
Dec 12 14:14:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.429291] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
Dec 12 14:14:43 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.697515] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input21
Dec 12 19:59:07 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.128083] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 12 19:59:07 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.281903] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
Dec 12 19:59:07 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.281929] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
Dec 12 19:59:07 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.281955] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
Dec 12 19:59:07 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.281987] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
Dec 12 19:59:07 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.282014] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
Dec 12 19:59:07 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.647408] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input21
Dec 13 02:22:12 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.129614] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 13 02:22:12 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.628939] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
Dec 13 02:22:12 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.628964] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
Dec 13 02:22:12 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.628988] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
Dec 13 02:22:12 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.629011] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
Dec 13 02:22:12 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.629035] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 13 02:22:12 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.017425] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input25
Dec 13 11:47:46 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.130047] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 13 11:47:46 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.310660] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
Dec 13 11:47:46 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.310712] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
Dec 13 11:47:46 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.311239] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
Dec 13 11:47:46 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.311384] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
Dec 13 11:47:46 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.311470] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
Dec 13 11:47:46 jividijuvent kernel: [    3.761529] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input21
Dec 13 13:29:32 jividijuvent kernel: [ 5474.829654] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device BenQ EW2775ZH (HDMI-0)
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.125455] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.633074] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input15
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.161480] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.161522] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.161558] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.161591] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input24
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.162550] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input25
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.125710] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426542] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426576] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426611] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426647] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426682] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input24
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.681425] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input25
```

syslog

```
grep -i hdmi /var/log/syslog
Dec 13 13:29:16 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[15220]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event14)
Dec 13 13:29:16 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[15220]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event10)
Dec 13 13:29:16 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[15220]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event11)
Dec 13 13:29:16 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[15220]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event13)
Dec 13 13:29:16 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[15220]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event15)
Dec 13 13:29:16 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[15220]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event16)
Dec 13 13:29:32 jividijuvent kernel: [ 5474.829654] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device BenQ EW2775ZH (HDMI-0)
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.125455] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.633074] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input15
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.161480] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.161522] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.161558] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.161591] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input24
Dec 13 13:30:00 jividijuvent kernel: [    5.162550] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input25
Dec 13 13:30:10 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1846]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event9)
Dec 13 13:30:11 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1846]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event16)
Dec 13 13:30:11 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1846]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event17)
Dec 13 13:30:11 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1846]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event18)
Dec 13 13:30:11 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1846]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event19)
Dec 13 13:30:11 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1846]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event20)
Dec 13 13:32:14 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3342]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event9)
Dec 13 13:32:14 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3342]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event16)
Dec 13 13:32:14 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3342]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event17)
Dec 13 13:32:14 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3342]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event18)
Dec 13 13:32:14 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3342]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event19)
Dec 13 13:32:14 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3342]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event20)
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    0.125710] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426542] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426576] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426611] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426647] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.426682] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input24
Dec 13 13:51:27 jividijuvent kernel: [    4.681425] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input25
Dec 13 13:51:42 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1659]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event20)
Dec 13 13:51:42 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1659]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event15)
Dec 13 13:51:42 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1659]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event16)
Dec 13 13:51:42 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1659]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event17)
Dec 13 13:51:42 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1659]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event18)
Dec 13 13:51:42 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1659]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event19)
```

syslog with display

```
grep -i fail /var/log/syslog|grep -i display
Dec 13 13:29:19 jividijuvent gsd-xsettings[15478]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
Dec 13 13:30:15 jividijuvent gsd-xsettings[2161]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
Dec 13 13:32:15 jividijuvent gsd-xsettings[3572]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
Dec 13 13:51:44 jividijuvent gsd-xsettings[1935]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
```

syslog with fail and gdm

```
grep -i fail /var/log/syslog|grep -i gdm
Dec 13 13:29:15 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[15220]: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Dec 13 13:30:10 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1846]: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Dec 13 13:32:13 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3342]: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Dec 13 13:51:41 jividijuvent /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1659]: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is solved on new Nvidia 440 driver, but I tested it on ubuntu 20.04 but there is a point that you need to notice.

At first time installation, I check the "install 3rd party software for graphic ... " in ubuntu installation process, after installation a Nvidia setting app was installed but it doesn't do anything and just opened an empty screen and did not give me any option and hdmi didn't work.
I installed ubuntu again without marking that option in the installation process and installed Nvidia driver via ubuntu additional driver setting and everything works fine.

I have to consider that hdmi port only works when you choose Nvidia graphic in Nvidia x server setting app because of this laptop configuration and hdmi does not work on intel graphic, both on windows and linux